# Override external CSS from YouTube

Tags: css, wordpress, youtube

Here is the external CSS from YouTube player:
https://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-player-webp-vflPkuiel.css

I embed video on my site and I want to override the original CSS with my CSS.

Original is:

```
.ytp-chrome-controls .ytp-button.ytp-youtube-button 
 {
    width: 51px;
 }
```

And i want override with this:

```
.ytp-chrome-controls .ytp-button.ytp-youtube-button 
 {
    width: 0px;
 }
```

How should the code look like, and where can I put the code to override the original CSS from the external link?

By the way, I have WordPress on my site.

Answer (score 0):

#### It's just not possible.

There is no way to override any css in YouTube because the player is hosted with an iframe.

The only options you have are the [embed parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=el#IFrame_Player_API), and unfortunately there's nothing that gives you this kind of customization at all.

Answer (score -1):

While it's not preferred to do in repeated fashion (though sometimes necessary), you could add the !important tag onto your CSS, as shown:

```
.ytp-chrome-controls .ytp-button.ytp-youtube-button { width: 0 !important; }
```

That should do it! Also, if you have 0 specified for a single CSS property, you do not need the unit included, such as px. Just something to keep in mind if your project is larger scale.

Tyler

Comment: When you added it to your HTML, did you place the code between <style></style> tags, within your <head></head> tags?

Comment: i add here: wordpress acp>appearance->editor->style.css